# Question about meaning of " Common Man's " & "mounting " is in the context here

Tags: word-meaning

> However, the **anti-corruption** Aam Aadmi (**Common Man's**) Party,
>   with its **stronghold** in the capital, Delhi, is **mounting** a
>   strong challenge.

My perception after checking in dictionary is that The party that most of its members are men ( common man ), and has the supportive area in Delhi is facing a big chalange.

I also would be greatful if you could help me saying what the use of  's  is here? And why the capital letters are used here? Common Man's.

Answer (score 1):

The terms "mounting" and "stronghold" are military terms used thus, and they are being employed here to invoke a metaphor of warfare to make political maneuvering seem more exciting and important.  A "stronghold" in the literal sense is a fortification (e.g. a castle or fort) and in a colloquial sense a location secured by one belligerent in an armed conflict ("Fallujah, along with nearby provincial capital Ramadi, was a stronghold of Sunni insurgents"); and attacks and sieges are "mounted" (but not, idiomatically, a battle, war, or ambush).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is capitalized because it is the proper name of a political party, the same way the Republican Party and Democratic Party are usually capitalized in English.

The phrase "Common Man" in English refers to the average person, or to the people of a country or region as a whole; it is used to contrast the "common man" with an elite or minority group.

The *'s* was probably added because, in English, the phrase "Common Man Party" sounds awkward. If the meaning of the party's name is "the party that represents the common man," or "the party that is concerned with the needs of the common man," then the most idiomatic way to express this in most English dialects is with a possessive; here, the "Common Man's Party."

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It should be *[Common Man Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aam_Aadmi_Party).*

But, it's the way Arvind Kejrival's party has been named by most of the English News Channels internationally. I guess you are an Indian and know Hindi. Though a literal translation of Aam Aadmi Party is actually Common Man Party, it has strongly created its image as a party **of** a common man in India. The party, as said by its founder (Arvind Kejrival), chiefly belongs to a common man (*aam aadmi - Hindi*). Since it's a proper noun of the party, it takes capital letters - *Common Man's Party.* The adjective *anti-corruption* is applied because that's the chief manifesto of the party and based on that, the party won Delhi Elections in 2013.

It has [stronghold](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/stronghold) in the capital as the party was unexpected to form the government in Delhi but due to great public support (see the definition of 'stronghold'). It is certainly [mounting](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/mount_1#mount_1__2) the challenge for the two major parties - BJP and Congress in India for the [Lok Sabha Election 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_general_election,_2014).